# How will I get the volume and surface area of the sphere?

Tags: solid-geometry

If a rectangular solid have edges, 4 cm, 5 cm and 7 cm, is inscribed in a sphere. How will I get the volume and surface area of the sphere?

Do I need to get the volume of the rectangular solid and use it to get the radius of the sphere?

Comment: If you visualize, then the diagonal of the cuboid will be a diameter of the sphere. Take out the diagonal of cuboid, and half it to get the radius.

Comment: Then the radius will be 4.74? Am I right?

Comment: @user114811:  that is approximately correct.  I think it would be better to leave it as $3\sqrt{10}$, which is exact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pythagoras twice to find the length of the long diagonal of the cuboid - the long diagonals will be diameters of the sphere.